# Remove the comments generated by cpp

Tags: gcc, ocaml, c-preprocessor

I use `#include ".../frontend/tokens.mll"` in `lexer.mll`, and then `cpp -C -P frontend/lexer.mll -o frontend/lexer_new.mll` to generate `lexer_new.mll`.

That worked until I upgraded my ubuntu from 12.04 to 14.04 yesterday.

The compilation gives an error:

```
ocamllex frontend/lexer_new.mll
File "frontend/lexer_new.mll", line 1, character 1: illegal character /.
make: *** [frontend/lexer_new.ml] Error 3
```

That is because in `lexer_new.mll` several lines of C comments have been inserted in the beginning:

```
/* Copyright (C) 1991-2014 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
   This file is part of the GNU C Library.

   The GNU C Library is free software; you can redistribute it and/or
   modify it under the terms of the GNU Lesser General Public
   License as published by the Free Software Foundation; either
   version 2.1 of the License, or (at your option) any later version.
   ... */
```

I don't remember if same comments were generated before upgrading.

Does anyone know how to get ride of these comments?

PS: the gcc version is : `gcc version 4.8.2 (Ubuntu 4.8.2-19ubuntu1)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**UPDATE**: It's possible that [pcu's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51203412/827263) is more correct than this one.

> You can use `cpp` with flag `-nostdinc` and do not use flag `-C`.

I'll leave this answer here.

---

Omitting the `-C` option appears to inhibit the inserted copyright message.

From the [documentation](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/):

> '-C'
>    Do not discard comments.  All comments are passed through to the
>    output file, except for comments in processed directives, which are
>    deleted along with the directive.
>
> You should be prepared for side effects when using '-C'; it causes
>    the preprocessor to treat comments as tokens in their own right.
>    For example, comments appearing at the start of what would be a
>    directive line have the effect of turning that line into an
>    ordinary source line, since the first token on the line is no
>    longer a '#'.

Comments in the source code are discarded by default. The `-C` option causes them to be passed through. Apparently in recent versions it also inserts that copyright message.

This *might* have other effects, good or bad. If `-C` was working for you before, it may be that some things that looked like C comments in your OCaml code were being passed through from 
`lexer.mll` to `lexer_new.mll`; omitting `-C` would cause them to be removed. If that's an issue, you might want to keep the `-C` option and add a filter after the preprocessor that removes the added comment. (Writing such a filter is left as an exercise.)

More information: running

```
cpp -C /dev/null
```

indicates that the copyright comment comes from `/usr/include/stdc-predef.h`:

```
$ cpp -C /dev/null
# 1 "/dev/null"
# 1 "<command-line>"
# 1 "/usr/include/stdc-predef.h" 1 3 4
/* Copyright (C) 1991-2014 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
   This file is part of the GNU C Library.
[39 lines deleted]
# 1 "/dev/null"
$
```

(The `-P` option was inhibiting the `#` directives that indicate where the text came from.) Apparently that file is included by default when preprocessing C source. It defines a few C-specific predefined macros such as `__STDC_IEC_559__` and `__STDC_ISO_10646__`.

Why were you using `-C` for non-C code?

Answer (score 3):

You can use `cpp` with flag `-nostdinc` and do not use flag `-C`.

Comment: Adding -nostdinc is the right answer here.  It is still possible to use -C.

Answer (score 1):

I ran into this problem recently (it was actually more complex, but boiled down to these issues), and described it and its solution in [CPP/GPP in Fortran variadic macro (plus Fortran // concatenation)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41335383/cpp-gpp-fortan-variadic-macro-fortran-plus-fortran-concatenation)

In short, the fix was to install an older version of cpp, which I learned can be done easily without having to use a previous version of the compiler.

On ubuntu 16.04

```
sudo apt-get install cpp-4.7
```

and then use

```
/usr/bin/cpp-4.7 -C -P myfile.F90 > myfile.f90
```